# Can't load "glyp" properly for opengl using freetype2

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype2

It seems as if freetype library isn't loading the font properly and doesn't convert it to bytes for later use as opengl texture.

Here is the result I'm getting with freetype:

[image: Image containing what is rendered]

I've already tried using another texture so it's unlikely that it's my texture manager's problem.

```
Font(const std::string font) //constructor
        :name(font)
    {
        std::string _font = "fonts/" + font + ".ttf";

        FT_Library ft;
        FT_Init_FreeType(&ft);


        FT_Face face;
        if (FT_New_Face(ft, _font.c_str(), 0, &face))
            EXIT_ERROR(-11);

        FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);

        for (unsigned int a = 1; a < 128; a++)
        {
            char c = a;

            if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
            {
                EXIT_ERROR(-12);
            }


//This just creates the FontTexture type, as I said before it works 
//fine,FontTexture is abstracted from BaseTexture which stores char* with 
//data. I also made sure that the stuff is loaded 
//there properly from inside FontTexture.


            FontTexture* _char = new FontTexture(
//here is buffer passing
face->glyph->bitmap.buffer, 
                0,
                { static_cast<float>(face->glyph->bitmap.width), 
                static_cast<float>(face->glyph->bitmap.rows) });

            _char->SetAdvance(face->glyph->advance.x);
            _char->SetBearing({ static_cast<float>(face->glyph->bitmap_left), 
                static_cast<float>(face->glyph->bitmap_top )});


//This just caches texture, so instead of loading it multiple times I can 
//just call "getTexture(name) store that pointer in the entitie's memory 
//and bind when Draw() is being called.
            TextureManager::getTextureManager().PrecacheTexture(std::to_string(a) + font, _char);

            Characters.insert(std::pair<char, FontTexture*>(c, _char));
        }

        FT_Done_Face(face);
        FT_Done_FreeType(ft);
    }
```

Comment: *"so it's unlikely that it's my texture manager's problem"* No, it is a problem with your texture manager. What is the texture format? Where do you `FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap`?

Comment: GL_ALPHA if that's what you are asking for.

Comment: glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA , size.x, size.y, 0, GL_ALPHA , GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_LocalBuffer);

Comment: Do `glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` before.

Comment: Does this have to be done each frame? I've done that before main loop.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Are you sure that the size of pixel is 1 byte?

Comment: Ok, I think you have to add it each time you generate new texture, am I wrong? I did that in that place and it worked.

Comment: No, [`glPixelStore`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) sets a global state, it is sufficient to do it once. Probably it is set back or you set it before the OpenGL context is valid.

Comment: I believe the context is already valid, I do it after glewInit().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter defines the alignment of the first pixel in each row (line) of an image when the image is read form the buffer. By default the this parameter is 4.
Each pixel of the glyph image is encoded in one byte and the image is tightly packed. So the the alignment of the glyph image is 1 and the parameter has to be changed before the image is read and the texture is specified:

```cpp
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

If that is missed, this would cause a shift effect at each line of the image (except if the width of the image is divisible by 4).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1) flag wasn't enabled. I probably enabled it before opengl had valid context.